# How can I order a vector by the order of its attributes in R?

Tags: r, sorting, vector, attributes, names

Say I have a vector and its name as follows:

```
       vct <- c(67, "apple", 88, "orange", 71)
names(vct) <- c("c1", "b2", "d66", "a65", "a11")
```

when I run:

```
sort(vct)
```

the vector is sorted based on elements; rather I want it to be sorted based on its names so that the vector is ordered "71", "orange", "apple", "67", "88".

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can `sort` or `order` the names :

```
vct[sort(names(vct))]
#vct[order(names(vct))]

#     a11      a65       b2       c1      d66 
#    "71" "orange"  "apple"     "67"     "88"
```

Comment: Thank you! This was really helpful. Do you know what I can do if I want one position, say b2 "apple" to be the first and the rest alphabetically?

Comment: I am not sure if I understand. Can you add that as a new question?

Comment: posted my question here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64889260/how-do-i-order-a-vector-by-attribute-names-in-r-but-keeping-the-first-element